# How to change child classes by changing only the parent class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with black and white cells and I want to create a button which changes the colors of cells.

I have done it by using for loop [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/p3qe7m5w/)

Now, I dont want to use the function below. Is it possible to change only the class atribute of whole table to change class of all *td* tag's?

```
function changeClors() {
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cSwap(cells[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the for loop, try toggling the `invert` class name on the table element. Then adjust the css accordingly, as in the snippet below:

```js
function cSwap(cell) {
  if (cell.className == "t")
    cell.className = "t2";
  else if (cell.className == "t2")
    cell.className = "t";
}

function tableCreate(n) {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.setAttribute('onclick', 'cSwap(event.target)');
  tbl.setAttribute('id', 'myTable');
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td)
      td.classList.add('t');
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}

function changeClors() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  table.classList.toggle('invert')
}
tableCreate(5);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 28px;
}

.t {
  background: white
}

.t2 {
  background: black
}

.invert .t {
  background: black
}

.invert .t2 {
  background: white
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Change colors" onclick="changeClors()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible you just need a css class for the `table` to do it and a function to toggle this class with your table.

This is how should be your css defined:

```
.myTable td{
  background: gray;
}
```

And this is the JS function to toggle it in the table:

```
function toggleClass(){
    var table = document.querySelector("table");
    if(table.className !== "myTable"){
                table.className = "myTable";
    }else{
            table.className = '';
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

This is an [updated **Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/p3qe7m5w/3/):

```js
function cSwap(cell) {
  if (cell.className == "t")
    cell.className = "t2";
  else if (cell.className == "t2")
    cell.className = "t";
}

function tableCreate(n) {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.setAttribute('onclick', 'cSwap(event.target)');
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td)
      td.classList.add('t');
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}

function changeClors() {
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cSwap(cells[i])
  }
}
tableCreate(5);

function toggleClass() {
  var table = document.querySelector("table");
  if (table.className !== "myTable") {
    table.className = "myTable";
  } else {
    table.className = '';
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 28px;
}

.t {
  background: white
}

.t2 {
  background: black
}

.myTable td {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Change colors" onclick="changeClors()">
  <input type="button" value="Change table" onclick="toggleClass()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just change the colors of the cells, you could toggle the class of the `table` and then use CSS selectors on the cells like the following:

```
.table-dark td { background-color: #000; }
.table-light td { background-color: #fff; }
```